# Received http2 header with status: 403 at Object.exports.createStatusError

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying add some data into **firebase** **firestore**.

But I getting following error stack:

```
(node:5448) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 1 CANCELLED: Received http2 header with status: 403
    at Object.exports.createStatusError ([...]\Back-end\node_modules\grpc\src\common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus ([...]\Back-end\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext ([...]\Back-end\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:564:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus ([...]\Back-end\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:614:8)
    at callback ([...]\Back-end\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js:841:24)
```

And this is my code :

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./test-project-xxx-firebase-adminsdk-xxxx-xxxxx.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://xxx-xxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com"
});

app.get("/b", (req, res) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ').set({
        capital: "sd"});
        console.log(cityRef)
    })

app.listen(port)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is internet problem cause iran blocked form google firebase and cant use some features of google firebase, means we need vpn to pass this blocks.

first i used proxy but it didnt work but when i used vpn it worked, data were sended to my firestore project.

Answer (score 1):

403 is authorization error - meaning your credentials are right, but are not allowed to execute the command/operation.
You should authorize the ID on fire-base and then retry.

Comment: i disable authorize in firestore security too.